# winapi get the mangled name from a function's address

Tags: c++, winapi, name-mangling

In my c++ applicatoin I have the virtual addresses of functions and I want to get their **mangled** names.
right now I can get only the unmangled name by using the winapi `SymFromAddr` function. 
is there a way to get the mangled names also ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [SymSetOptions()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681366%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  You want to turn off the `SYMOPT_UNDNAME` option to see the mangled name.

So, roughly:

```
  DWORD options = SymGetOptions();
  SymSetOptions(options & ~SYMOPT_UNDNAME);
  if (SymFromAddr(hProcess, dwAddress, &dwDisplacement, pSymbol))
  {
      // etc...
  }
  SymSetOptions(options);
```

Comment: Thanks , this worked but I also had to turn on the SYMOPT_PUBLICS_ONLY flag