# String name of template function

Tags: c++, templates

I know you can use the preprocessor to get the textual name of a standard function at compile time via `__func__`

My question is, is there any way to get the textual name of a template function including its specific implementation details (mangled is better than nothing)?

For example,

```
template <typename T>
void myFunction() {
    std::cout << //Function name here;

};
```

Output:

> ```
> myFunction<int>(); -> "myFunction<int>" (or mangled name)
> myFunction<char>(); -> "myFunction<char>" (or mangled name)
> ```

Comment: This is compiler specific. For gcc, `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` does the trick.

Comment: There's no standard way. Check out this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40806790/get-a-c-function-mangled-name-at-compile-time-or-runtime

Comment: C++20 added a standard way to get function name w/o preprocessor - see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For use with g++ you can use `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`.

So for

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void myFunction() {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
};

int main() {
    myFunction<int>(); 
    myFunction<char>();
}
```

I get

```
void myFunction() [with T = int]
void myFunction() [with T = char]
```